# DropDownList in a User Control - How to get it so list items can be added at design time?

Tags: asp.net

I have a user control that basically just has a dropdownlist in it (more to it than that obviously, but the dropdown is all you see).

In Visual Studio, you can add items to a regular drop down list from the designer.  How can I extend this functionality to my user control?

If I type out the items manually like below, it works when testing in the browser, but gives me errors in the designer

```
<uc2:Input_DropDownList ID="Input_DropDownList1" runat="server">
    <ListItems>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Apples" Value="0" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Oranges" Value="1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Grapes" Value="2" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Strawberries" Value="3" />
    </ListItems>
</uc2:Input_DropDownList>
```

Error:

```
 Error Creating Control - Input_DropDownList1
    Type 'System.Web.UI.UserControl' does not have a public property named 'ListItems'
```

Codebehind:

```
<PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)> _
    Public ReadOnly Property ListItems() As ListItemCollection
        Get
            Return InputField.Items
        End Get
    End Property
```

I understand WHAT the issue is... but I'm not sure how to work around it.  Any help appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The control property exposing the ListItems() should have these attributes:

```
<DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content),
NotifyParentProperty(True),
PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerDefaultProperty)>
Public ReadOnly Property ListItems() As ListItemCollection
    Get
        Return InputField.Items
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  That code doesn't seem to help.  I am still getting the same error on the designer.  If I use InnerDefaultProperty, "ListItem" doesn't show up in intellisense at all.  If I change it to InnerProperty (as I was using), it shows up in intellisense, but errors out in the designer.

Comment: odd. i have that code rite now to test it and they works just fine. no error at all. have you recompiled your project?

Comment: Yep. I copied and pasted your code verbatim.  When I try to add listitems to the user control, it throws up a big ugly error saying system.web.ui.usercontrol has no public property called listitems ... despite the property being there, and being public.

Shows up as a property in intellisense:
http://i.imgur.com/ZXICWKp.png 

Once I actually put the code in there, the designer freaks out:
http://i.imgur.com/EKQ0xCb.png

Comment: a-ha, the error is in design view! afraid to say that that is not possible. you might want to read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2080154/2264365)